# SSRS Report Unauthorised

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS reporting service in my MVC application. I am using some reports and accessed these reports from web application by specifying URL like this

and passing username, password and domain as credential.

When I use this code on local it's working fine but when I use same code on the live environment its giving a

> 401 unauthorised error.

Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong? One thing to mention that when I am using this locally both the database and the deployed code are in same domain but on live environment both database and code are on different domains.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you specifying the URL?  The "like this" doesn't actually show anything?

Comment: I am specifying it like http://<Servername>/reports?%2f<foldername>%2f<reportname>&rs:Command=Render?&<p‌​arametername>=<parametervalue>&rs:Format=pdf also sending my server credential with domain

Actually I am accessing it from web application created in MVC and accessing it from controller by using WebClient to download the result as pdf.

Comment: I am using these line of code

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("me", "12345", "mydomianname");
File(webClient .DownloadData(reportURL), "application/pdf", "fileName");